# How do you delete Battlefield 4 DLC?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-4

I want to add Battlefield 4 DLC packs like Final Stand, but because it is a big download I'm worried that even if I delete Battlefield 4 from my game data utility file the DLC will still be in the system. If that's the case, I'd want to know how you would delete the actual DLC for more space just I case I need room for other games like GTA 5. I don't care if I have to redownload everything when I play again but I don't want to add DLC packs if they can't be deleted from PS3 console. Thanks for your time. I tried to explain it as clearly as I could so please help.

Comment: "I'm worried that even if I delete battlefield 4 from game data utility file the dlc will still be in the system" - Is this based on anything or not? I don't know Battlefield at all, but it seems like a weird worry to have to me.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they are deleted when you remove the game ... It would be extremely bad design otherwise ...

They become part of the game and when you remove the game, the DLC files are deleted as well ...

Comment: Alright thanks. Would suck if the DLC mb data stayed on my console. It is a small console but thank you for ur post.

Answer (score 0):

From the main horizontal menu (the XMB), go to the Game entry. I suspect you'll find that the DLC, and perhaps some patched data, linger on in there. Give it a look, and let me know if you find anything. Could be quite a few gigabytes of space to be freed up.